# What, if any, are the differences between implementing one class as a child of another versus having the child employ an instance of the parent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, instance

so please bear with me on this.

I struggle some in understanding certain aspects of the concept of inheritance.

As such, I was wondering, what would be the difference between implementing one class, say "Child", as the child of another, say "Parent", versus simply making "Child" create and utilize a "Parent" object within itself?

For example, given the parent class as:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def parent_method(self):
        print(self.arg)
```

What would be the difference between making and implementing a child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super().__init__(arg)

Child('foo').parent_method()
```

Versus:

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.parent = Parent(arg)

    def call_method(self):
        self.parent.parent_method()

Child('foo').call_method()
```

Both of which simply print:

```
foo
```

Is the only difference here syntactical? I mean, it definitely seems more efficient to use inheritance here, but is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You are speaking about inheritance vs composition. That is a rather broad discussion, unfortunately I'm not sure it's a good fit for this site.

Comment: At it's core, inheritance is a tool for code reuse. Notice how you are already repeating yourself in the alternative to inheritance.

Comment: Was going to say exactly that, one is inheritance and the other composition, one means a class is a subset of another one, the other means it is composed of them.
Think about man and woman inheriting from human, VS human/man/woman being composed of hand and foot (a human can grab but he will use his hand). It is a matter of how the dependencies should work, and who holds responsibility for what.

Comment: For one thing, in your second example the parent's code operates on its own state which is separate from the child's.

Comment: I suggest this old article https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/tag/inheritance.html

Comment: Using inheritance, `Parent` is part of the *interface* for `Child` as well as the implementation. Using composition, it's only part of the implementation.

Comment: Your question is very broad, For a start, in one example you have 1 object and the other you have 2.

Comment: Type checkers like mypy, abstract base classes, `isinstance` works nicely, etc.  I like to use a car metaphor for inheritance: Every `Prius` *is a* `Car`.  A `Prius` doesn't have a `Car`.  Also, inheritance let's you do neat stuff like `class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): pass`